# Can FullCalendar be used in an offline environment

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a use case where the website that is using FullCalendar will be disconnected from the internet 100% of the time. Will this still work, or will it throw some sort of error related to not being able to authenticate the license?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened when you tried? Most fullCalendar installs don't require a license anyway, it's only if you use the premium Scheduler plugin. Anyway if you look at one of the demos of the Scheduler on the site (e.g. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/addResource-demo) you can see by debugging with the Network tools in your browser that it never makes any kind of call back to the fullCalendar server to check the license details. I haven't looked at the source but I'd assume there's just an algorithm in there to do a basic validity check. Again...you just can try it easily, to verify.

Comment: I'd have thought that the main issue you'll get if the calendar is disconnected from the internet 100% of the time is that it'll be a bit useless - if the whole point is to display a calendar of events, where is it going to get the data from? If it uses static data, it's not much use if it can never ever be updated. Unless I have missed some subtlety here?

Comment: ADyson, it will be used in a closed environment where the users are scheduling resources available in that closed off environment. I will need the the premium scheduler and likely need the SaaS license, although this is still being researched. I can try and see what happens and report back.

Comment: Right so it's just disconnected from the public internet, rather than disconnected from any network at all. "offline" usually means the latter in my experience. So I thought the calendar would have nowhere to save it's events. Anyway like I said I've seen no evidence that the Scheduler calls home to check the license, but you can easily try it out

Comment: I would like to know this also. A license key is required but I need this to work on a LAN without internet. (So no calls home)